# Menu toggle working on every second click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Js Code:**

```
$(document).click(function () {
  $('.hide-menu').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $('body').toggleClass('hide-sidebar');
    });
});
```

-The hamBurger menu has a permanent class- hide-menu.
- by default, there is 'hide-sidebar' class in the body tag

Comment: and what's your question? what did you try to solve it? what didn't work?

Comment: Toggle should be (show/hide) on every click. 1.show 2.hide - repeat

Comment: Could you add the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code works if you remove the $(document).click() part of it. You also don't need the preventDefault() (but it also works if you leave it in the code)

```js
$('.hide-menu').click(function(event) {
  $('body').toggleClass('hide-sidebar');
});
```

```css
.hide-sidebar nav {
  display: none;
}


/*
  These nav styles are only to highlight the showing nav, they are not needed and can be restyled as wished
*/
nav {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="hide-menu"> Hide Menu </button>

<nav>
  <a href="#"> link </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only need

```
  $('.hide-menu').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('body').toggleClass('hide-sidebar');
  });
```